# BizTalk relationship between AS2 MDN report and Tracked Service Instances

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

Is it possible to find a relationship between the AS2 Message report and Tracked Service instances report?

I have the scenario of receiving messages via AS2 and sending them to an SFTP. What I would like to do is to have visibility from the EDI message to the converted message and back. I know that tracked messages are related using `InterchangeId`, but I did not find a way to filter on this in AS2 report.

We also have BizTalk 360, so if this helps, just let us know.

Comment: @andreicorovei please see this